# Oracle BI Publisher Failed to load XML if setting parameter and trying to view data

Tags: sql, bi-publisher, oracle-bi

When I try to run this SQL with manual values everything is OK

```
SELECT * 
FROM epayment_application 
WHERE time_stamp 
BETWEEN 
TO_DATE('03/07/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
AND 
TO_DATE('05/07/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

When I replace values with parameters and try to view data

```
SELECT * 
FROM epayment_application 
WHERE time_stamp 
BETWEEN 
TO_DATE(:DateFrom, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
AND 
TO_DATE(:DateTo, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

It gives Failed to load XML error. Type of parameters is Date and format is also dd/mm/yyyy.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: try this format dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: No, nothing changed.

Comment: your query runs well with TO_DATE(:DateFrom, 'dd/mm/yyyy')AND 
TO_DATE(:DateTo, 'dd/mm/yyyy') or only in bip has problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the TO_DATE from the query in BIP like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM epayment_application 
WHERE time_stamp 
BETWEEN 
:DateFrom
AND 
:DateTo
```